# Finding the maxima of a logarithm with the form: $x(a \ln(mx+c) + d)$

Tags: calculus, logarithms, maxima-minima, lambert-w

Currently trying to build an analytical model that requires knowing the point of maxima for the equation:

$y = x(a \ln(mx+c)+d)$

The parameters are such that the maxima can be graphically shown to be $x>0$, with $-1<a<0$.

I would like to be able to quickly know where this maxima is using the parameters, as there will be thousands of models and I would rather not have to do it by fitting.

Currently my result (as shown below) involves the Lambert function and I haven't come across that before. So my question is kind of two-fold: is my result correct and can this be simplified with the knowledge that the maxima is in a reasonable region of x?

My method:

Differentiating with the product rule I get:

$\frac{dy}{dx} = d + \frac{amx}{c + mx} + a\ln(c + mx) = 0$

Substituting in $V = mx+c$ to simplify things:

$d + \frac{a(V-c)}V + a\ln(V) = 0$.

Now solving for V,

$V_{max} = \frac{c}{W(c . \exp(1 + \frac{d}{a}))}$,

where W is the product log or Lambert function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

[I've attached an example distribution with parameters of $a=-0.15$, $m=0.000043$, $c=0.43$ and $d=0.31$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55jbJ.png)

Thank you for any help you can give!

Comment: Lambert is a very  beautiful function with a lot of applications. Here, in the Search bar, just type *Lambert* :2748 entries. Whet more precisely to you need about it ? By the way, **Welcome to the site !!**

Comment: Thanks! I guess my question is whether it has an approximation that can be used to simplify it in the region of small i.e. $0<x<10$ for W(x). I'm hoping to be able to just stick the parameters quickly for thousands of curves. Maybe the answer is obvious, but it looks quite intimidating for the first time seeing it!

Comment: For the computation of Lambert $W(t)$, you could use Corless algorithm which is quite fast. Otherwise, the series expansions give in the Wikipedia page.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful! I will take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As asked in comment, I had a look to what could be an approximation of $W(x)$ for the range $0 \leq x \leq 10$.

For obvious reasons, the Taylor series built around $x=0$ would not work over this large range since it is
$$W(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{n^{n-1}}{n!} x^n$$ showing how fact the coefficient vary.

However, and this is totally empirical, it seems that, over this range, $x^{3/4}W(x)$ is close to linearity; have a look at

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot+x%5E(0.75)+ProductLog(x)+from+x%3D0+to+x%3D10

So, the idea was to write
$$W(x)=\sum_{n=1}^p a_n t^n \qquad \text{where} \qquad t=x^b$$ Using nonlinear regression for such an empirical model with $p=5$, what is obtained is summarized below
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval}
   \\
 a_1 & +0.7293417468 & 0.00067739 & \{+0.7280125,+0.7306710\} \\
 a_2 & -0.1989488190 & 0.00084036 & \{-0.2005979,-0.1972997\} \\
 a_3 & +0.0385896461 & 0.00028194 & \{+0.0380364,+0.0391429\} \\
 a_4 & -0.0040728293 & 0.00004093 & \{-0.0041532,-0.0039925\} \\
 a_5 & +0.0001741237 & 0.00000218 & \{+0.0001698,+0.0001784\} \\
 b   & +0.8488289012 & 0.00101683 & \{+0.8468335,+0.8508243\} \\
\end{array}$$ 
For the values gives in the example, this would lead to $0.1300$ for an exact value equal to $0.1366$.

Comment: That's very useful to know! Thank you very much!